# Why would a transaction be dropped from transaction pool

Tags: transactions

What could be a reason, reasons why a transaction is dropped from the transaction pool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients can decide what criteria transactions must meet to remain in the local pool.

When those criteria are not met, the transactions are removed from the pool. This leads to different client instances and implementations having different transactions in their pools.

In Geth, for example, you have the following options:

```
TRANSACTION POOL OPTIONS:
  --txpool.nolocals            Disables price exemptions for locally submitted transactions
  --txpool.journal value       Disk journal for local transaction to survive node restarts (default: "transactions.rlp")
  --txpool.rejournal value     Time interval to regenerate the local transaction journal (default: 1h0m0s)
  --txpool.pricelimit value    Minimum gas price limit to enforce for acceptance into the pool (default: 1)
  --txpool.pricebump value     Price bump percentage to replace an already existing transaction (default: 10)
  --txpool.accountslots value  Minimum number of executable transaction slots guaranteed per account (default: 16)
  --txpool.globalslots value   Maximum number of executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 4096)
  --txpool.accountqueue value  Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots permitted per account (default: 64)
  --txpool.globalqueue value   Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 1024)
  --txpool.lifetime value      Maximum amount of time non-executable transaction are queued (default: 3h0m0s)
```

Perhaps of most interest here are the `*slots` and `*queue`s values, as well as the 3 hours in `--txpool.lifetime`.

---

In my admittedly old version of Parity:

```
  --tx-queue-size LIMIT          Maximum amount of transactions in the queue (waiting
                                 to be included in next block) (default: 1024).
  --tx-queue-gas LIMIT           Maximum amount of total gas for external transactions in
                                 the queue. LIMIT can be either an amount of gas or
                                 'auto' or 'off'. 'auto' sets the limit to be 20x
                                 the current block gas limit. (default: auto).
  --tx-queue-strategy S          Prioritization strategy used to order transactions
                                 in the queue. S may be:
                                 gas - Prioritize txs with low gas limit;
                                 gas_price - Prioritize txs with high gas price;
                                 gas_factor - Prioritize txs using gas price
                                 and gas limit ratio (default: gas_price).
  --tx-queue-ban-count C         Number of times maximal time for execution (--tx-time-limit)
                                 can be exceeded before banning sender/recipient/code.
                                 (default: 1)
  --tx-queue-ban-time SEC        Banning time (in seconds) for offenders of specified
                                 execution time limit. Also number of offending actions
                                 have to reach the threshold within that time.
                                 (default: 180 seconds)
```

(There may be other in-built criteria that are not configurable, but you get the general idea.)

These are just the options that are available to vanilla clients. You are free to edit the code however you like.

Answer (score 2):

One scenario in which this could happen is that, with block N being the latest block on the main ("longest") blockchain, let's say two different miners create two different blocks, creating two different versions of the blockchain - one with miner M1's block as block (N+1) and the other with miner M2's block as block (N+1). They would have a different set of transactions because, as transactions propagate through the network, the set of unmined transactions that the two miners see may be different. Now, other miners could add future blocks to either of these two versions. Say the version with miner M1's block "wins" and becomes the main chain, miner M2's block will get left out or "orphaned". Any transactions that were in M2's block but not in M1's block are now not in the main chain. If they do not make it in within the next "few" blocks, then they may need to be sent again.